Задача про часы, почему решается именно так?
2 день изучаю Питон и наткнулся на такую задачку:

Дано число n. С начала суток прошло n минут. Определите, сколько часов и минут будут показывать электронные часы в этот момент. Программа должна вывести два числа: количество часов (от 0 до 23) и количество минут (от 0 до 59). Учтите, что число n может быть больше, чем количество минут в сутках.

Вот решение
n = int(input())
hours = n % (60 * 24) // 60
minutes = n % 60
print(hours, minutes)

Можете мне объяснить самое решение, а то я не понимаю строчку hours = n % (60 * 24) // 60. Почему применяется деление с остатком, почему применяется деление без остатка?

%(60*24) - обрезает "лишнее" кол-во минут, чтобы было минут <= в сутках. Если же минут гарантированно <= в сутках, то можно эту операцию убрать

применяется деление с остатком  - не совсем точно: вычисляется остаток от деления

В условиях задачи есть предупреждение, о том что на вход может быть
подано количество минут большее чем содержится в сутках.
В одном часе 60 минут, в сутках 24 часа, (60 * 24) = 1440 минут в сутках.
Если на вход получено число 2440 - это 1 день, 16 часов, 40 минут.
Обратите внимание, что на ваших часах дни не отображаются!
Следовательно, Вам надо уменьшить n на количество минут кратное 1440.
В этой строке hours = n % (60 * 24) // 60:


получаете остаток от деления n на 1440 - n % 1440 = 1000
целочисленным делением 1000 // 60 = 16 получаете часы.



n = int(input())
hours = n // 60
minutes = n % 60
print(hours, minutes)

// - это целочисленное деление
n // 60 - количество целых часов (60 минут)
% - получение остатка от деленияn
n % 60 - остаток минут (< 60)

Что будет, если ввести 2000?
